# How to limit the use of an Xbox one Controller to one PC user?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, gaming, xbox-one

My gaming rig is setup where both my sibling and I could play games simultaneously through Remote Desktop. However, I use an Xbox one controller to play my games and for some reason while I play my game, my sibling's game is also being controlled by the controller. Is there a way for me to limit the controller input to one profile? I am willing to do whatever setup necessary to be able to play games simultaneously without interruption. I have only achieved it with Fortnite so far because they have an option to ignore gamepad inputs. I run windows 10 Pro 64 bit. P.S. I've tried using RemoteFX but the controller wont show up in it for the life of me.